# MySQL query to select a certain day in the past?

Tags: mysql, sql, joomla

I have a joomla website and I want to make a query that it could run with a cronjob every day. It would look for any articles 30 days old and delete the articles this specific day.

I can make a simple query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  `ibps6_content`
    WHERE created > '2013-10-16' AND created < '2013-10-16'
```

But I don’t know how to make it specify the last 30 days, instead of hardcoding the dates.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need mysql [DATE_FORMAT(date,format)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

Please try to set your query as:

```
DELETE FROM `ibps6_content` WHERE created > DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This works but deletes all articles last 30 days. How can i delete the articles that i created 30 days ago, only this specific day?

Comment: You just have to replace `>` with `=`.

Comment: Don't use dateformat when you can use a date datatype.

Answer (score 0):

Which rdbms? 
In oracle you can use select based on `sysdate` which represents the current date/time.

Example:

`select * from ibps6_content WHERE created between sysdate - 30 and sysdate`

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL, you could use the following:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ibps6_content
WHERE
    created BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Note that this will give you the articles written up to the specific time that you run the article. To remove the times and utilize just the dates, you could use:

```
DECLARE @CurDate DATETIME;
SET @CurDate = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()));

SELECT
    *
FROM
    ibps6_content
WHERE
    created BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -30, @CurDate) AND @CurDate
```

Answer (score 0):

If created is a date datatype in the table

```
DELETE FROM ibps6_content WHERE created = CURRENT_DATE -INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

If it's datetime use DATE(created)